# An error occurs when you try to assign a data type to a input in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

Back Story:
I am new to python and was making a very simple program to find the greatest of three numbers while doing so I found it was not giving back the right answer. I thought it might have been a logical issue and pursued to make a flowchart and search examples of the same program online and I found many but I could not find any difference between those programs and mine until I read through it line by line and realized that it was not an issue of the comparison but instead of the method I was taking inputs. I was taking inputs like this:

```
num1 = float=(input("Enter first number: "))
```

this extra = sign after the float seemed to fix the problem. However, I was then wondering why python allowed this and if it does what purpose does it serve? What is python actually doing here? And how does it change the outcome of my program?

My program:

```
num1 = float=(input("Enter first number: "))
num2 = float=(input("Enter second number: "))
num3 = float=(input("Enter third number: "))

if (num1 > num2) and (num1 > num3):
   print("The largest number is",num1)
elif (num2 > num1) and (num2 > num3):
   print("The largest number is",num2)
else:
   print("The largest number is",num3)
```

My inputs:

```
 Enter first number: 11
 Enter second number: 6
 Enter third number: 5
```

The Output:

```
 The largest number is 6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is legal Python, but not very useful:

```
num1 = float=(input("Enter first number: "))
```

This is a chained assignment statement, which assigns the value returned by `input` to two names: `num1` and `float`.

Doing so does not call the builtin `float` function—in fact, it hides the builtin function, so you can never call it again. (If you try, you’ll get an `TypeError` about strings not being callable.)

This is legal because `float` and other builtin functions aren’t keywords, or anything else special; they’re just variables in the builtin namespace.

What you want here is definitely to call `float`, not to hide it, like this:

```
num1 = float(input("Enter first number: "))
```

---

So, why does it seem to work? Really, it’s just coming close to working by accident. Your `num1`, `num2`, and `num3` and up as strings, like the string `'6'` (and `float` ends up as the same string as `num3`). It’s perfectly legal to compare two strings with `>`. However, it isn’t really what you want. Strings are compared alphabetically, so `'6' > '11'` (because the first character, `6`, is greater than the first character, `1`). That’s why you want to convert these strings to numbers: the float `6.0 < 11.0`, just as you’d expect for numbers.

If you were having problems in your code, adding an `=` here is not the way to fix them. At best, you’re just hiding the bug behind another bug so you don’t even get to the real problem anymore.

Comment: So if I understand correctly it converts float from a keyword to just a regular variable and then assigns it the input?  Therefore not converting the input to a float and just keeping it as a raw string

Comment: @ArmaanSengupta Mostly right. But it was never a keyword, it's just a normal variable. Its value is originally the `float` conversion function (or, actually, the `float` type); you replace it with a string value like `'11'`. The rest is completely right—you're not converting the input to a float, you're just keeping it as a string (and that's why `'6'` is the largest number instead of `11.0`).

Answer (score 0):

With the extra `=`, you're assigning the returning value of `input()` to `float` as a variable, shadowing the built-in `float()` function. The value is then assigned to `num1` (and `num2`, `num3` in the following lines).

You should remove the extra `=`s so that the inputs can be properly converted to numbers for numeric comparisons; otherwise your comparisons will be based on strings, which is why `'6'` is considered larger than `'11'` in your example output.

Comment: Can you assign a variable to a data type? Or do you mean to say that it is getting converted to a float? And how is 6 being considered larger then 11, if they are strings how would python even make this comparison?

Comment: In Python, all non-statement keywords can be used as variable names and be assign to, including built-in function names. `float` isn't actually a data type, but a built-in function (actually a constructor function the `float` built-in class), when called, constructs an object of float data type. abarnert has explained how string comparison works so I won't repeat it.

Answer (score 0):

`num1 = float = (input("Enter first number: "))`

This code reads the user's input and assigns that value to both `num1` and `float`.

You probably wanted this instead:

`num1 = float(input("Enter first number: "))`

As it stands, your code is comparing `num1`, `num2` and `num3` as strings, in which case `6` is indeed the "largest" string.

Answer (score 0):

By assigning `num1`, `num2`, `num3` and `float` to `input` functions you will get following variables:

```
num1 = '11'
num2 = '6'
num3 = '5'
float = '5'
```

The `=` operator is an assignment operator which helps you to shadowing the `float` funtion. With using it, you set a new value to `float` which sets to `'5'` with last input. With this values, you compared three strings and `'6'`is greater than `'11'` so you get `num2` as the largest input.
Shadowing a builtin function is not recommended, but it is a flexibility of python.